# F test to compare 2 average variances in r

Tags: r

I made an experiment and divided the results into 2 groups - good and average. I want to test the assumption of equal variances, but the "var.test" function doesn't exactly answers my need. In each group I have data from several teams, so what i would like to do is compare their **average** variance, that is each group's variance and then test the mean of that variances. Just to make it clear, an example of my dataset:

```
    Team    bottles 
1   2         10    
2   2         10    
3   2         12    
4   2         10
5   2         10    
6   2         10        
25  4         12    
26  4         10    
27  4          7    
28  4          8    
29  4          8    
49  6         10
50  6         10
51  6          7
52  6         10
53  6         10
54  6         10
55  6         10
56  6          9
73  10        10
74  10        12
75  10         9
76  10         9
77  10         8
78  10         8
79  10         9
```

I want to compute first the variance of group 2, then group 4 and then avarage it. Then do the same thing for different groups in other dataset, and finally make a comparison between the average variance between the 2 groups.

Thanks for answer!

Comment: I think we need an example with more groups (and less rows for group) in order to start helping you. The code you've tried so far is also important. Finally, have you checked `?anova`  and `?aov`?

Comment: I edited the post so it will have more observations.